# Directly accessing Hyper-V console via RDP

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, console, hyper-v

I am wondering if there is a chance to directly connect to a VMs console via RDP. It seems the hyper-v manager is basicaly doing the same when connecting to a VMs console.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to remotely connect to VMs without starting the hyper-v manager.

The protocol is RDP-based, but it requires some additional extensions that are only usable by a couple clients.  The one you get from Microsoft, and one Open Source client.

You have two choices Install the Hyper-V admin tools on your workstion and run the `c:\program files\Hyper-V\{version}\vmconnect.exe`.  The exact filename may be different.  On my Windows 8.1 system it is `C:\Program Files\Hyper-V\6.2\vmconnect6.2.exe`.

When using vmconnect you just specify the Hyper-V server and the name of the virtual machine.

If you don't want to your can't install the Hyper-V client tools on your machine as an alternative you can also download a  build of [freerdp](http://www.freerdp.com/).  The freerdp client has the ability to connect to a [hyper-v guest](http://www.cloudbase.it/using-freerdp-to-connect-to-the-hyper-v-console/).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to connect to Hyper-V guest virtual machine directly through Remote Desktop by installing the Hyper-V Admin Tool for Windows 7.

Here are the links and more explanation.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/schadinio/archive/2010/07/09/installing-hyper-v-manager-on-windows-7.aspx

and

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same problem.  It seems if the Windows OS on the VM is already up and running when you open the HyperV console, it will connect to an RDP session and NOT the console session.  I found this out becuase the local policy on the hardened OS image I loaded from had RDP logins (even local admins) and I couldn't gather why it was telling me I needed rights for Remote Desktop connections when I was at the "console"

My solution:  Shutdown the VM, open a VM console connection to the VM, and power it back up.  You are now on the actual "console" session of the VM.

When the system boots and switches to the windows graphical desktop, by default the HyperV vmconnect console pops up a window to choose the resolution and local resource settings (unless you've checked "save for future connections" box).  Just cancel this prompt (hit Escape) and you'll remain on the console session.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This seems to work, and is separate from the 'enhanced' session, which not every guest supports.

Answer (score 0):

Once the VM is created it is treated like any other machine. If it is a Windows server, as long as you have your remote settings allowing access you should be able to rdp into the machine.

Comment: Seems the OP wants to RDP to the _Console_ of the Windows box, not just to a regular RDP session.

Answer (score 0):

Testing empirically with the current version of Hyper-V on Windows 10, I came up with the following: In Virtual Machine Connection, there is a setting **View** -> **Enhanced session**.

1. When I need console access, I *un*check Enhanced session (clipboard integration is disabled)
2. When I don't need console access, I *select* Enhanced session (much better user experience with working clipboard integration)